# Numbers $2, \sqrt{6}, {9 \over 2}$ are part of geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got this question and I can't understand how those three are part of geometric sequence since they don't have common quotient? I mean,  $${\sqrt{6} \over 2}  \neq {{9 \over 2} \over \sqrt{6}}$$

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive terms?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have misunderstood the question. Assuming that the question meant that they don't necessarily be consecutive terms, you can say that they are all of the form $a.r^n$. Then, dividing two terms at a time, you get that $\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt 2} $ and $\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\sqrt 2}$ are both powers of $r$.